# Отмена запуска intent при отсутствии программы-обработчика

Tags: android

Хочу запустить `intent` навигации в приложении, сейчас столкнулся с проблемой:

в случае отсутствия приложения `GoogleНавигация` на телефоне, приложение крашится.

Как добавить условие, чтобы при отсутствии вышеуказанного приложения, выводилось, например, *Toast-сообщение*, указывающее на отсутствие приложения для навигации?

```
button_navi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent33 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Россия+Самара+Ленина+34"));
            startActivity(intent33);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
else
    ...
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073832/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent

Answer (score 5):

Можно так же проверить на наличие `Google Maps` вот таким способом:

```
public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled() {
    try {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        return true;
    } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```